# Simple sass to css transpilation with Webpack

Tags: webpack, sass

I'm having a hard time coming up with a simple setup to handle SASS->CSS transpilation.

I have a few entrypoints for sass that I want converted to css files. Webpack seems to be doing a lot of unexpected stuff for me, like creating js files with a whole bunch of code, and then making me use MiniCssExtractPlugin to actually get the css files. And even then, the original .js artifacts still remain, and I am forced to manually exclude them with a TerserPlugin.

Is there really no simple setup where you have N js entrypoints, M sass entrypoints, and the sass ones are simply transpiled down to css that's put in a specific folder? No fancy js loading, nothing else. I've spent so long just trying to get normal css. Why is it so roundabout? :'(